# Android HttpPost does not send POST values at all

Tags: java, php, android, httprequest

I am trying to do an Http request to the following PHP code:

```
<?php

var_dump($_POST);

?>
```

Here is my Android Java code to send the request:

```
        String stringURL = "http://*I EDITED OUT MY IP*/mediatheque_api";

        List<NameValuePair> postVars = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);

        postVars.add(new BasicNameValuePair("req","listemedias"));
        postVars.add(new BasicNameValuePair("no","12345"));

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(stringURL);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postVars));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

            if (httpEntity != null){
                System.out.println("Not Empty");
                String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
                System.out.println(responseBody);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Empty");
            }

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Here is what is outputted in the LogCat:

```
07-04 17:13:15.274: I/System.out(20547): Not Empty
07-04 17:13:15.274: I/System.out(20547): array(0) {
07-04 17:13:15.274: I/System.out(20547): }
```

As suggested in the comments, I echoed the value of $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'], it says I am requesting a GET rather than a POST. Issue is, my Apache server's config hasn't been touched and I'm clearly doing a POST request.

It seems that my HttpPost does not send any POST variables, even though I'm supposedly encoding it through the URL. If I simply go to the page with a browser, I also get array(0) {}, because there isn't any POST variables in the request. I've tried to tinker around with it since yesterday and I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. What is the issue?

Comment: check that a post is even being performed - what's `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` show?

Comment: There you go. You'll never get any values in $_POST if a GET is being performed. You are, however, setting up a post in the code, so make sure that there's no redirects or whatnot taking place that could be converting your post into a get.

Comment: A redirect? How? I haven't touched the Apache config file. When I use my browser to get to the page, I also get a "GET".

Comment: Your browser is _supposed_ to do a GET when you just hit a page from the URL bar. This code, however, isn't.

Comment: In that case, is there anything I can do to remedy the problem? Is the way I call the URL here wrong? I call the apache server directly with its IP rather than its domain, and there is no .htaccess file set up in that directory. Mod_Rewrite is also disabled.

Comment: I'm going to guess the code you show *isn't* what is actually running, or you have something every wrong happening on the server side. There's nothing wrong with the code you post, and `DefaultHttpClient` isn't broken in android.

Comment: Test your php script with [hurl.it](http://www.hurl.it/) to check if it works correctly.

Comment: Completely forgot about hurl. Thanks for reminding me that site exists.

Looks like I spent one day looking at mites in the code. I'm running off an index.php file, and my URL is the following: "http://*I EDITED OUT MY IP*/mediatheque_api" and does not point correctly to the directory, thus I get redirected to "http://*I EDITED OUT MY IP*/mediatheque_api/", resulting in a GET request. It works fine once I add the slash.

Comment: You can also use $_REQUEST array in your php scripts when you're not sure about request type - it consists of variables from $_POST, $_GET and $_COOKIE.

Comment: I'll remember that. I didn't figure it out until I saw the entire header.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what doesn't work with my code. This line in particular:

```
String stringURL = "http://*I EDITED OUT MY IP*/mediatheque_api";
```

I never pointed to the directory containing the index.php file properly, thus resulting in a HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently response, which would redirect me to http://*I EDITED OUT MY IP*/mediatheque_api/. I forgot to add that final slash. It now works fine.